# Executing synchronous queries to Google Cloud Endpoints on iOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I guess this is really a feature request to Google, but I'm curious if anyone knows a work around.  I'd like to execute a **synchronous** query request to a GAE Endpoints api.

In Android executing a request is synchronous.  Then you put it into an AsyncTask to make it work in the background.

In iOS executing a request is asynchronous.  You simply pass in a callback block.

I'm converting an Android app into an iOS app and it'd be really nice if they used the same mechanism.  For example there are times when I WANT a synchronous query.  It just makes my code easier and I know to put it on a background thread.

So my question is this... is there any way (hacky or not) to block until the iOS query completes?

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: We worked out a hacky lock trick for our code years ago.  It works for us, but it's all in Objective-C.  Just let me know if you need snippets.  Google has now deprecated Endpoints 1.0 and will shut it down on 8/2/2018.  Haven't looked into Endpoints 2.0 yet (officially they call it Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine).  Info about the Endpoints 1.0 shutdown: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/

Answer (score 4):

You can wait on the call to finish with code with a timeout using code similar to this. Obviously you wouldn't want to do this on a UI thread but this would ensure your completion handlers run in serial.

```
NSLog(@"Before API Call");
GTLServiceTicket *apiCall = [apiService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                   GTLHelloworldHelloGreeting *object,
                                                   NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Starting completion handler");
    NSArray *greetings = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: object, nil];
    greetingsRetrievedFromAPI = greetings;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"DisplayGreetings" sender: self];
    NSLog(@"Ending completion handler");
}];
[apiService waitForTicket:apiCall timeout:100000 fetchedObject:nil error:nil];
NSLog(@"After completion handler");
```

Comment: I tried something similar by waiting for a condition after issuing the call to `executeQuery` on the main thread (I also tried from an `NSOperationQueue`) and signalling the condition in the completion handler. However, this blocks the main thread. Is `waitForTicket:` the only way to go? Could it e.g. be that the completion handler is always called on the main thread?